# regex match whitespaces inside <> tags

Tags: python, regex, string

Suppose I have string like this:

`<ENAMEX TYPE="GPE">Moscow and Miami</ENAMEX> are good, but <ENAMEX TYPE="GPE">New York is better</ENAMEX>`

How do I match whitespaces within <> tags only using regex? Basically what I'm trying to achieve is replacing whitespaces inside <> tags (like in `ENAMEX TYPE`) with underscore. So that my output string would look like this:

`<ENAMEX_TYPE="GPE">Moscow and Miami</ENAMEX> are good, but <ENAMEX_TYPE="GPE">New York is better</ENAMEX>`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Perhaps this will help:

```
s = '<TYPE="GPE" CODE="123" LOC="AAA">Moscow and Miami</ENAMEX> are good, but <ENAMEX TYPE="GPE">New York is better</ENAMEX>'

import re
def sub(match):
    return match.group(1).replace(" ", "_")

re.sub(r"(<[^<>]*>)", sub, s)
```

It gives:

```
'<TYPE="GPE"_CODE="123"_LOC="AAA">Moscow and Miami</ENAMEX> are good, but <ENAMEX_TYPE="GPE">New York is better</ENAMEX>'
```

Comment: Thank you @bb1 it almost works, but inside the tags there could be more than one attributes: `TYPE="GPE" CODE="123" LOC="AAA"` etc.

Comment: It handles multiple tags now.